# Why doesn't my tkinter callback return a password?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import string
from random import randint, choice
from tkinter import *


def generate_password():
    password_min = 6
    password_max = 12
    all_chars = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation + string.digits
    password = "".join(choice(all_chars) for x in range(randint(password_min, password_max)))
    password_input.delete(0, END)
    password_input.insert(0, password)


window = Tk()
window.title("Henerateur de mot de passe")
window.geometry("720x480")
window.config(background='#4065A4')

frame = Frame(window, bg='#4065A4')

width = 300
height = 300
image = PhotoImage(file="password.png").zoom(35).subsample(32)
canvas = Canvas(frame, width=width, height=height, bg='#4065A4', bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.create_image(width / 2, height / 2, image=image)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

right_frame = Frame(frame, bg='#4065A4')

label_title = Label(right_frame, text="Mot de passe", font=("Helvetica", 30), bg='#4065A4', fg="white")
label_title.pack()

password_input = Entry(right_frame, text="Mot de passe", font=("Helvetica", 30), bg='#4065A4', fg="white")
password_input.pack()

generate_password_button = Button(right_frame, text="Generer", font=("Helvetica", 30), bg='#4065A4', fg="#4065A4", command=generate_password())
generate_password_button.pack(fill=X)

right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

frame.pack(expand=YES)

window.mainloop()
```

What should happen is that a new random series of letters, digits and punctuation signs appears every time you click the `generate_password_button`; however, when you click it nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
generate_password_button = Button(right_frame, text="Generer",
                                  font=("Helvetica", 30), bg='#4065A4',
                                  fg="#4065A4", command=generate_password())
```

you assign `generate_password()` as the command to be executed when the button is pressed. The effect of this is to use the return value of `generate_password()` as the command to be executed, which is `None` as it doesn't explicitly return anything, and nothing will happen.

Instead, you want to pass the function *itself*, **without calling it**, i.e.:

```
generate_password_button = Button(right_frame, text="Generer",
                                  font=("Helvetica", 30), bg='#4065A4',
                                  fg="#4065A4", command=generate_password)
```

Now, when your button is pressed, the `generate_password` function (callback) will be called.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. If my answer solved your problem, please check out [what to do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer will let us mark the question as solved.